# I need to export my Scrollview as Multi page PDF

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to export my ChatView as PDF, my function `exportToPDF` is doing the job, but if the chat is too long then it cuts the page, I need to save all the chat into the PDF, how can I do that? Here is the code:

```
import Speech
import SwiftUI

struct ChatView: View {
    var chatId: UUID
    @FocusState private var isEditing
    @State private var isTranscriptionLongEnough = false
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    @EnvironmentObject var chatViewModel: ChatViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { _ in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(chatViewModel.chats.filter { $0.id == chatId }) { chat in
                            ForEach(chat.messages) { message in
                                messageView(message: message)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter a message...", text: $chatViewModel.currentInput)
                    .onAppear {
                        isEditing = true
                    }
                    .focused($isEditing)

                Button {
                    if !chatViewModel.currentInput.isEmpty {
                        chatViewModel.sendMessage(chatId: chatId)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                }
                Button {} label: {
                    Image(systemName: "mic.circle.fill")
                }
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1, maximumDistance: .infinity, pressing: { isPressing in
                    if isPressing {
                        startRecording()
                    } else {
                        stopRecording()
                    }
                }, perform: {})
            }
            .padding()
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        turnSpeechSynthesisOnandOff()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: chatViewModel.isSpeechSynthesisPaused ? "speaker.slash.fill" : "speaker.3.fill")
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        exportToPDF()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onDisappear(perform: {
            chatViewModel.isSpeechSynthesisPaused = true
        })
    }

    func turnSpeechSynthesisOnandOff() {
        chatViewModel.speechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
        chatViewModel.isSpeechSynthesisPaused.toggle()
    }

    func exportToPDF() {
        let outputFileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("\(chatId).pdf")
        let pageSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

        // View to render on PDF
        let myUIHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: self.environmentObject(chatViewModel))
        myUIHostingController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize)

        // Render the view behind all other views
        guard let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
            print("ERROR: Could not find root ViewController.")
            return
        }
        rootVC.addChild(myUIHostingController)
        // at: 0 -> draws behind all other views
        // at: UIApplication.shared.windows.count -> draw in front
        rootVC.view.insertSubview(myUIHostingController.view, at: 0)

        // Render the PDF
        let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: pageSize))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {
                try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { context in
                    context.beginPage()
                    myUIHostingController.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
                })
                print("wrote file to: \(outputFileURL.path)")
            } catch {
                print("Could not create PDF file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

            // Remove rendered view
            myUIHostingController.removeFromParent()
            myUIHostingController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func startRecording() {
        // Solicitar permiso para acceder al micrófono
        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { authStatus in
            if authStatus == .authorized {
                // Iniciar reconocimiento de voz
                let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.current)
                let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

                recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, _ in
                    if let result = result {
                        var transcription = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                        if !transcription.isEmpty {
                            isTranscriptionLongEnough = true
                            chatViewModel.currentInput = transcription
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Configurar entrada de audio desde el micrófono
                let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                do {
                    try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .default)
                    try audioSession.setActive(true)

                    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
                    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
                    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
                        request.append(buffer)
                    }

                    audioEngine.prepare()
                    try audioEngine.start()
                } catch {
                    // Manejar errores de configuración del audio
                    print("Error al configurar la grabación de audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func stopRecording() {
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        if isTranscriptionLongEnough {
            chatViewModel.sendMessage(chatId: chatId)
            isTranscriptionLongEnough = false
        }
    }

    func messageView(message: Message) -> some View {
        HStack {
            if message.role == .user { Spacer() }
            Text(message.content)
                .padding()
                .background(message.role == .user ? .blue : .gray.opacity(0.7))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            if message.role == .assistant || message.role == .system { Spacer() }
        }
    }
}

struct ChatView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChatView(chatId: UUID())
            .environmentObject(ChatView.ChatViewModel())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I follow this video on youtube for a very clean implementation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDQ5ENvJxyc

It saves a single page PDF, but it prints all the view taking a dynamic height.